# Array of arrays - why I have one more level of Arrays than I think I should?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

My question is very specific, and I can't seem to find a close enough question anywhere else to allow me to understand this.  Basically, I've found a solution to my problem, but I don't understand why it works.  I've come to it via a lot of research and then a lot of trial and error.

Short explanation: getting a two column MySQL database into an array in PHP then into javascript is resulting in an array of arrays of arrays.  I'm not understanding why it is 3 arrays deep and not 2.

Here is the long explanation with code examples:

I am getting all of my two column MySQL database via:

```
     while ($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {   // get the SQL data
        $columnA[] = $row['columnA'];         // get columnA (array)
        $columnB[] = $row['columnB'];         // get columnB (array)
     }
    $combinedData[] = [$columnA, $columnB];   // combine them in an array to split up later
    echo json_encode($combinedData);          // send to javascript file via ajax
```

I then send this to my javascript file, which does a `JSON.parse`:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'loader.php',    // the php code from above
    type: "POST"
}).done(function(data) {
        console.log("columnA: "+JSON.parse(data)[0][0][0].toString());  //why [0][0][0] ... why 3 arrays deep?
        console.log("columnB: "+JSON.parse(data)[0][1][0].toString());
    }
);
```

This is the ONLY way I've found I can get each individual cell output into my javascript.  Two things don't make sense to me though:

MY QUESTION:  `$combinedData` is an array of arrays, so why, when I get data from php into javascript, do I have to go 3 arrays in... `JSON.parse(data)[0][0][0]` ?

I understand the last array is the array of individual cells (`$columnA` from the php), and the 2nd one is the array of columns (`$combinedData` from the php).  Where is the first one coming from?

I also don't why I have to split $row and then recombine them.  If I just echo $row I can't (figure out how to) parse the data correctly in js.

Comment: **1.** First array `$row['columnA'];` **2.** Second array `$columnA[]` **3.** Third array `[$columnA, $columnB];` and how you didn't expect this

Comment: @AlanMachado: so? if it was `$columnA = $row`, then only the LAST record from the fetch loop would be saved.

Comment: @MarcB I've figured that, I've got this urge to comment first and think later, lately... working on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
    $combinedData[] = [$columnA, $columnB];

1.                    ^------------------^ wrap two arrays in a new array
2.               ^^----------------------- append array from #1 to a NEW array
```

You end up with arrays nested 3 deep. All you needed was

```
$combinedData = [$columnA, $columnB]; 
             ^--- no []
```

Comment: yes!  Thank you! I guess I didn't see that the [] was creating a new array outside the other.

Answer (score 3):

Since `$combinedData` is an array, and that you are appending `[$columnA, $columnB]` to it, this is what you currently get:

```
$combinedData = array(
    0 => [$columnA, $columnB]
)
```

My understanding is you don't want to append `[$columnA, $columnB]` to `$combinedData`, you want `combinedData` to **be** `[$columnA, $columnB]`. This will give you what you want:

```
$combinedData = [$columnA, $columnB];   // combine them in an array to split up later
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just...

```
while ($row = $table->fetch_assoc()) {   // get the SQL data
    $combinedData[] = $row;         
 }
```

Think your would have what you expect

Comment: I wasn't getting the correct output into my javascript that way. I kept getting: Array (which wouldn't work with .toString()) or `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` if I did `json_encode`.
There is probably a better way with that... which was also something I was wondering.  But I missed that solution before coming to this one which finally worked.

Comment: Got it!  I think I just wasn't parsing the data in javascript correctly before I found my php solution.  Thank you!  This gives me the rows in javascript, while my OP gives me the columns - I originally thought columns would be better, but I now will evaluate which is better for the next step in my code.